# Returning ViewModels' instance through CommandParameters

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ioc-container

I have a Parent ViewModel, bound to the Parent Window. Inside, there is an ItemsControl, that is Bound to a Collection of Child ViewModels.
The ItemsControl creates UserControls (Child Views) that get their DataContext as ChildViewModel (automatically, according to how ItemsControl Works).

It might be worth noting, that I am using Castle Windsor as IoC. 
I have also tried resolving the child ViewModels through a (currently working) abstract factory, but it didn't help. I even tried with the child ViewModel registered as a singleton, but still - cannot be found inside the collection.

So I dumbed down the problem question to simple class instantiation.

**Now, what I wanted to:**

Each Reminder (UserControl) has a Button, that represents closing.
This button is bound to the Parent ViewModel like this:

```
CloseCommand="{Binding ElementName=level1Listener, Path=DataContext.ReminderBoxCloseCommand}"
```

Where `level1Listener` is the name of the `ItemsControl`.

So far everything works fine, UserControls get created and all bindings work. But:

> When I click the Close button, the ViewModel isn't removed from the collection - even though the bound command executes. It seems, that the instances of `ReminderBoxViewModel` returned by ANY of the UserControls, do not exist in the collection - but the UserControls even showing up depend directly on their existence.
>
> When i simply remove an element at a certain index - all works fine.
>
> How could the UC return something different as its' Data Context?

**How is this possible, or am I missing something entirely?**

**This is my PhoneWindow View:**

```
<Window x:Class="NoContact.Views.PhoneWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoContact.Views"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:avalon="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"
    xmlns:usercontrols="clr-namespace:NoContact.UserControls"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:NoContact.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PhoneWindow" Height="600" Width="980"
    Background="#22282a">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="600" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="10, 10" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowBorderStyle}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="180" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Margin="-1,-1" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowBorderStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Margin="15">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <DrawingImage>
                                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#ffcd22"
                                             Geometry="{StaticResource phoneIconGeometry}" />
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            </DrawingImage>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBlockStyle}">Telefon</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel> 
            </Border>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="10,20,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBlockStyle}">Imię:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Height="30" Margin="46,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="10,20,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBlockStyle}">Nazwisko:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Height="30" Margin="10,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="10,20,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="top">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBlockStyle}">Data:</TextBlock>
                            <usercontrols:DateTimePicker Height="30" Margin="40,0,10,0" BorderBrush="#ffcd22" BorderThickness="1" Background="#15151a" Foreground="#ffcd22"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="10,20,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBlockStyle}">Email:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Height="30" Margin="26,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="10,20,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBlockStyle}">Telefon:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Height="30" Margin="10,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="10,20,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="top">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBlockStyle}">Nr. Zamówienia:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox Height="30" Margin="10,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <avalon:TextEditor Margin="10,10" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowAvalonEditStyle}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" WordWrap="True">

                </avalon:TextEditor>
            </Grid>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Margin="-1,0,-1,-1" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowBorderStyle}">
                <Grid>
                    <Button Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}">Gotowe</Button>
                    <Button Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}">Anuluj</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowBorderStyle}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowBorderStyle}">
                <usercontrols:ImageButton x:Name="addButton" Style="{StaticResource addImageButtonUCStyle}" Text="Dodaj Termin" ClickCommand="{Binding Path=AddReminderCommand}">

                </usercontrols:ImageButton>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="-1,0,-1,-1" Style="{StaticResource phoneWindowBorderStyle}">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#15151a">
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="level1Listener" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Reminders, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ReminderBoxViewModel}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <usercontrols:ReminderBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#22282a" Foreground="#ffcd22" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                              AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="140" CloseCommand="{Binding ElementName=level1Listener, Path=DataContext.ReminderBoxCloseCommand}"
                                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                    <Rectangle Height="1" Margin="10,0" Fill="#ffcd22" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**PhoneWindow (View) Code behind:**

```
namespace NoContact.Views
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for phoneWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class PhoneWindow : Window, IView
{
    public IViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }
    private IWindowManager _windowManager;

    public PhoneWindow(IViewFactory context, IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _windowManager = windowManager;

        var obj = context.Create<IPhoneWindowViewModel>();
        ViewModel = obj;
        this.DataContext = obj;
        context.Release(obj);
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        _windowManager.RemoveFromWindowList(this);
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
}
```

**And this is the MainViewModel:**

```
public class PhoneWindowViewModel : BindableBase, IPhoneWindowViewModel
{
    private IWindowManager _windowManager;

    private ObservableCollection<IReminderBoxViewModel> _reminders;

    public PhoneWindowViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        _windowManager = windowManager;

        _reminders = new ObservableCollection<IReminderBoxViewModel>();
    }

    public ICommand ReminderBoxCloseCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<ReminderBoxViewModel>(CloseReminderBox); } }
    public ICommand AddReminderCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(AddReminder, () => true); } }

    public ObservableCollection<IReminderBoxViewModel> Reminders
    {
        get { return _reminders; }
        set
        {
            _reminders = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delegates closing the window, associated with 
    /// this ViewModel instance.
    /// </summary>
    private void CloseWindow()
    {
        _windowManager.CloseWindow(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// "Closes" the Reminder Box by deleting it from the Collection 
    /// </summary>
    private void CloseReminderBox(ReminderBoxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        Reminders.Remove(viewModel);
        var index = Reminders.IndexOf(viewModel);
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the reminder to the Collection
    /// </summary>
    private void AddReminder()
    {
        Reminders.Add(new ReminderViewModel());
    }
```

Lastly, my userControl Code:

```
namespace NoContact.UserControls
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for ReminderBox.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ReminderBox : UserControl
{
    #region Dependency Properties

    public Brush CloseButtonBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(CloseButtonBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CloseButtonBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public new Brush Background
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public new Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseButtonBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CloseButtonBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(ReminderBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly new DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Background", typeof(Brush), typeof(ReminderBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly new DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Foreground", typeof(Brush), typeof(ReminderBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CloseCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ReminderBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(ReminderBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion



    public ReminderBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
}
}
```

Reminder XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NoContact.UserControls.ReminderBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoContact.UserControls"
         xmlns:usercontrols="clr-namespace:NoContact.UserControls"
         xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:NoContact.Helpers"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="ReminderBoxUC"
         d:DesignHeight="130" d:DesignWidth="400">
<Grid>
    <Border Background="{Binding ElementName=ReminderBoxUC, Path=Background}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="20" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource flatButtonStyle}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="0,10,10,0"
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=ReminderBoxUC, Path=CloseCommand}">
                <Border Name="closeButtonBackgroundBorder" CornerRadius="5" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonReminderBox_BorderUCStyle}">
                    <Image Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                       Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=ActualHeight}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <DrawingImage>
                                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding ElementName=ReminderBoxUC, Path=CloseButtonBrush}" Geometry="{StaticResource closeIconGeometry}" />
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            </DrawingImage>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Border>
            </Button>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0">
                <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding ElementName=ReminderBoxUC, Path=Foreground}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Przypomnij:
                </TextBlock>
                <RadioButton Name="RemindOnceRadioButton" IsChecked="True"
                                 Foreground="{Binding ElementName=ReminderBoxUC, Path=Foreground}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,0,0,0">1 Raz</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Name="RemindMultipleRadioButton"   
                             Foreground="{Binding ElementName=ReminderBoxUC, Path=Foreground}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25,0,0,0">Wielokrotnie</RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>

            <DockPanel Grid.Row="2"
                            Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <usercontrols:DateTimePicker Height="25" Margin="10,0" BorderBrush="#ffcd22" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="#ffcd22" Background="#15151a" Width="150" />
                <ComboBox Width="150" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0" Style="{StaticResource comboBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={helpers:EnumBindingSource {x:Type local:TimePeriods}}}"
                          SelectedIndex="0" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>        
</Grid>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="local:ReminderBox">
        <Setter Property="CloseButtonBrush" Value="#ffcd22" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=closeButtonBackgroundBorder, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="CloseButtonBrush" Value="#22282a" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

As for The ReminderViewModel, it is currently empty, except for an inheritace from (also currently empty) interface IReminderViewModel.

Comment: Your `Close Command` should be executed from `PhoneWindowViewModel`. This way you can pass the ViewModel through command parameter i.e. `CommandParameter={Bindinig .}` and in your `PhoneWindowViewModel` you remove it from your collection. Binding to the `PhoneWindowViewModel` should looks like `Command="{Binding DataContext.CloseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"`

Comment: @XAMlMAX I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, because to me this is exactly what is happening now. The collection resides inside the PhoneWindowViewModel, and the command does as well. The thing is - that the command itself executes properly, its just that the viewModel of the Reminder Control that's returned with CommandParameters seem to not exist inside the Collection.

Comment: OK. I can see the whole thing now. Do you get the index in this line `var index = Reminders.IndexOf(viewModel);`?

Comment: @XAMlMAX yes - but this line is Just for debugging - to see If the viewmodel returned from the commandparameters can be found anywhere in the collection. Suprisingly, it returns -1. The actual work should be done in the linę above: Reminders.remove(viewModel);

Comment: Did you try CommandParameter="{Binding}"? Also make sure that you don't explicitly set the DataContext of the ReminderBox  somewhere.

Comment: @mm8 CommandParameter="{Binding}" does not work either. I'm guessing that's because it returns a UserControl itself, and not the ViewModel - which I'm interested in.
The only thing that comes to my mind is the IoC Container Somehow messing it up, by injecting the ViewModel Somewhere, for some reason, where it shouldn't be?

Comment: It returns the DataContext of the UserControl.

Comment: ...which seems to be a ReminderBox in your case? Or why is the data type set to usercontrols:ReminderBox?

Comment: @mm8 You are correct. still, did not change anything. Also, I just deleted all references of ReminderBoxViewModel inside the IoC Installers - just in case - didn't change anything.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the CloseReminderBox method, does it get hit? And what if you change the type of the source collection to ObservableCollection<ReminderViewModel> to make sure that you are not mixing types? You should read this by the way: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @mm8 Right - forgot to mention that. I have checked for the types mix, does not help. I tried both interfaces and classes. And as I said in the post - the CloseReminderBox method does get hit, and the "debugging" messagebox gives out -1.

Comment: Is the viewModel parameter null?

Comment: @mm8 I was just to say that I just noticed it.

Comment: You seem to be adding ReminderBox elements to the source collection but you should add ReminderBoxViewModel. It makes no sense to set the DataType of a DataTemplate to a view type...

Comment: @mm8 I see. I must have misunderstood how DataType works.
I have changed it to a viewModel type, but I am still getting nulls.

Comment: "a viewModel" should be <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ReminderBoxViewModel }"> and the CommandParameter property should be set to {Binding}. Then you shouldn't get a null reference passed to the CloseReminderBox method assuming you see the DataTemplate and that you don't set the DataContext of the view somewhere else. But please provide a full repo of your issue if you need any further help.

Comment: @mm8 I have added code for context. This should be everything that can interact with the ReminderBox. Personally, I cannot find anything that would disrupt the binding to be null.

Comment: I was referring to the ReminderBox view.

Comment: @mm8 Please refresh, It also has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that althought you're setting your `CommandParameter` DP to a Binding to the current `ReminderBoxViewModel`, you aren't using it anywhere in the ReminderBox.

In the Reminder XAML you correctly bind the `Command` of the Button to the `CloseCommand` of your ReminderBox, you aren't setting the Button's `CommandParameter` to the `CommandParameter` of your ReminderBox.

The relevant code of the ReminderBox's XAML:

```
<Button ...
        Command="{Binding ElementName=ReminderBoxUC, Path=CloseCommand}"
        CommandParameter"{Binding ElementName=ReminderBoxUC, Path=CommandParameter}">
    ...
</Button>
```

Comment: I was so focused on more complex reasons, that I overlooked the simplest one. That's it, thank you :)